# PrimeFaces.current().focus Not working on commandButton

Tags: jsf, primefaces

PrimeFaces.current().focus method works with inputTexts but with a commandButton I see no results, alternative I can use executeScript but the idea is to use focus for this kind of requeriment:

This works:

```
PrimeFaces.current().executeScript("document.getElementById('frmAperturaCajaMasiva:btnAceptarAperturaCajaMasiva').focus();");
```

This works on inputTexts but not working on button:

```
PrimeFaces.current().focus("frmAperturaCajaMasiva:btnAceptarAperturaCajaMasiva");
```

Any idea why? its the same thing but different in both commands

This is the code of the button on the xhtml nothing fancy :)

```
<p:commandButton id="btnAceptarAperturaCajaMasiva"
                    value="#{etiquetasMsg.cerrar_caja}" styleClass="cds-icon-button"
                    icon="cds-icon aprobar"
                    disabled="#{aperturaMasivaMB.blBtnProcesar}"
                    title="#{tooltipsMsg.cierrecaja_masiva_cerrar}"
                    onclick="if(!confirmarSeleccionTabla(PF('dtbFrmCajaWv'),null)){ return false; }"
                    actionListener="#{aperturaMasivaMB.validarCierreCajaMasivo}"
                    rendered="#{adminRestriccionMB.validarRestriccion('BTN_CERRAR_CAJAMASIVO')}" />
```

Comment: What did you debug?

Comment: @Kukeltje Debugged the managedbeam mate, its passes through the code I posted, and it works with executeScript but not with Focus, its really weird

Comment: @Kukeltje do you think its because I haven't updated the jsf to 2.3?

Comment: No I don't, but it is not difficult (easy even) what the differences in the pages/responses are

Comment: @Kukeltje Damn I need to do that JSF upgrade to 2.3 but im afraid to touch those standalone.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes I know why.  The focus method in PrimeFaces specifically excludes buttons it was intended to focus input fields.  Here is the source code.

```javascript
focus: function(id, context) {
    var selector = ':not(:submit):not(:button):input:visible:enabled[name]';
```

Notice the "not(:submit):not(:button)" in the Jquery selector.

Source code:
https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/master/primefaces/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/core/core.js#L699-L728

Comment: Hey dude where did you find this info??

Comment: I updated the answer with a link to the PrimeFaces Source code where its happening.

Comment: Hmm INTERESTING why would they do that! thanks mate I guess I will continue using PrimeFaces.current().executeScript("document.getElementById('frmAperturaCajaMasiva:btnAceptarAperturaCajaMasiva').focus();"); for focusing buttons :)

Comment: Hey @Melloware just wanted to let you know something curious about focusing buttons in PF 7.0, if I use PrimeFaces.current().executeScript("document.getElementById('frmAperturaCajaMasiva:btnAceptarAperturaCajaMasiva').focus();"); for focusing a button, it won't work alone, it must be precede by PrimeFaces.current().focus("frmAperturaCajaMasiva:btnAceptarAperturaCajaMasiva"); and then it will focus the button, any idea why? its like he need the primefaces focus call and also the execute script focus call to focus on a button, for inputtext it will work with only one of those calls.

Comment: In 3.5 I only needed PrimeFaces.current().executeScript("document.getElementById('frmAperturaCajaMasiva:btnAceptarAperturaCajaMasiva').focus();"); for focusing button, without precede of PrimeFaces.current().focus("frmAperturaCajaMasiva:btnAceptarAperturaCajaMasiva");

Comment: Why not just call 1 JS line `PrimeFaces.focusElement($('#frmAperturaCajaMasiva\\:btnAceptarAperturaCajaMasiva'));`

Comment: I didn't saw that method focusElement, gonna try it, why do you use those \\?

Comment: Hmm it won't work mate, only if I call focus function and then also executeScript for focus it will finally focus the button, for inputtext I just use .focus and it works, the thing is that for buttons I should be only using executeScript but for some reason it needs focus method too

Comment: That doesn't make sense.

Comment: So what do I do?

Comment: Keep debugging.  There has to be a reason why it works and doesn't work.